# optimise mysql query with IN clause for 10,000 records

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

EDITED:
So this is the query I use:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM contacts
   WHERE id in
       (
    SELECT DISTINCT contacts.id
    from contacts INNER
   JOIN contacts2tags ON contacts.id = contacts2tags.contactid
   WHERE ( tagid in ( 178 ) ) )
```

It runs very slow. Suggestions to optimise it?
I have added indexes but it still needs improvement!

**contacts** table contains id, first_name, last_name, ..and **tags** table contains id, name. **contacts2tags** table contains contactid and tagid which are same as contacts.id and tags.id respectively
EXPLAIN:
[image]

Please have a look at: [optimise mysql query with LIKE operator for 10k records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154636/optimise-mysql-query-with-like-operator-for-10k-records/21155012#21155012)

It was stupid of me to post a portion of the query here. Sorry about that :P

Comment: Can you put create syntax from the tables contacts and contacttags and also a explain from the query. Since youre using having there will be a filesort and temptable. So, it also depends on your server capacity.

Comment: I would hope you have an index on c.id and an index on t.tagid, and in which case I would expect MySQL to find the records on the contacts2tags table then join those against contacts. If there is no index on t.tagid but instead you have one on t.contactid it would either have to do a non keyed search on one or the other table, depending on which it choses to use first.

Comment: thanks. I do have indexes on both tagid and id

Answer (score 0):

I just compared queries
select benchmark(1000000, 1 in(1,2,3,4,5)); took 0.122 sec
select benchmark(1000000, (1=1 or 1=2 or 1=3 or 1=4 or 1=5)); took 0.088 sec

So can you try using or instead of in i am not sure but for in index is also not used so just give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use or instead of IN.

Your query should be:
   SELECT c.id       FROM contacts c     inner join contacts2tags t       on c.id = t.contactid        WHERE **( t.tagid =7 or t.tagid =4)**         GROUP BY  c.id      HAVING count(distinct t.tagid) = 2

Answer (score 0):

The plan you've shown us says that the optimizer only expects to have to fetch 3 rows of data. If its "slow" (you didn't say how slow) then presumably the plan is not optimal or your data is very skewed.

The first thing I'd check is whether the index stats are up to date. Then I'd try...

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM contacts c
inner join contacts2tags t 
  on c.id = t.contactid 
   WHERE t.tagid in (7,4)
```

To find out how many rows the DBMS is actually processing to resolve the query. If this number is very high then you're unlikely to get much of a performance improvement from tuning the query.

....but one potential solution would be....

```
SELECT c.id 
FROM contacts c,
  contacts2tags t4,
  contacts2tags t7,
WHERE c.id = t4.contactid
AND c.id = t7.contactid
AND t4.contactid=t7.contactid
AND t4.tagid=4
AND t7.tagid=7;
```

Comment: sorry, the actual no of rows is 11000. i'm editing the post with the actual snapshot(as on actual server)

Comment: plz check the edited query. i had posted a part of it earlier. sorry

Comment: You've completely changed the query from your original question. Why are you using the contacts table twice?

Comment: i know this is annoying but please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154636/optimise-mysql-query-with-like-operator-for-10k-records I posted this one^^ separately as a new post was likely to get a quicker response. PS I really need to work on learning sql. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the need for using a sub query in your updated query. Try the following (although preferably use the names of the required columns from contacts rather than contacts.*).

```
SELECT DISTINCT contacts.*
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN contacts2tags ON contacts.id = contacts2tags.contactid
WHERE tagid IN ( 178 )
```

Make sure there is an index on tagid on the contacts2tags table.

If contactid / tagid on contacts2tags is unique (which I would hope) then no need for the DISTINCT. This can be enforced by adding a unique covering index on tagid / contactid (in that order to allow this key  to be used in the WHERE clause).

Comment: That can't be good?! Assuming there are multiple id's per tag you'll get multiple contacts records that you'll then 'fix' by using DISTINCT again, giving the server much more work to do than is strictly needed.

Comment: The alternative is to use a join against a sub query which would result in the join being non indexed, or using an IN with a sub query as in the original post, which would again be non indexed. In this case it will probably do a query against contacts2tags against the indexed tagid column, then join that against contacts using the primary key id field. Distinct is a nasty, but not really avoidable with any efficiency if there is more than one tagid in the IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you would first JOIN contacts and contacts2tags in a subquery and then use that to filter contacts again !?!

I presume the reason is that you already optimised the DISTINCT onto the id (lean) id field instead of doing it afterwards on the entire contacts.* record.

Anyway, what you actually should do IMHO is the following:

```
SELECT *
 FROM contacts
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM contacts2tags 
                WHERE contacts2tags.contactid = contacts.id
                  AND tagid in ( 178 ) )
```

This will NOT double contacts records as the query processor knows it can stop searching once it finds a first hit in the contacts2tags table.

As for using IN() vs using OR... I doubt it will make a lot of difference as internally it probably gets translated to the same thing anyway (?!)

Comment: hey, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154636/optimise-mysql-query-with-like-operator-for-10k-records/21155012#21155012   I think since there are many records in contacts2tags table as well, the query became even slower when i used WHERE EXISTS(..) or it could be some other reason. I am an amateur in MySQL. Thanks for bearing with this post. :D

Comment: The other post looks mostly about LIKE and text-matching; I doubt the WHERE EXISTS() has anything to do with that one. In my (MSSQL-based) experience WHERE EXISTS() should never be slower than JOINING, especially not when that JOIN then would require an additional DISTINCT later on again. But maybe mysql is peculiar?